# Let z = 1 + i. Find the real and imaginary parts of z^19

Tags: complex-numbers

Let z = 1 + i. Find the real and imaginary parts of $z^{19}$

Comment: we get $$(1+I)^{19}=-512+512I$$

Comment: Note that $z^2 = 2i$.  Does that help?

Comment: I understand the answer, but I still don't quite get this. Is this a constant, or is it something from this specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quickly determined that $\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} = e^{\pi i/4}$ and 
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^{19} &= e^{19 \pi i/4} = e^{4 \pi i + 3 \pi i/4} = \cos(4\pi) \, \left( \cos\left(\frac{3 \pi}{4}\right) + i \, \sin\left(\frac{3\pi }{4} \right) \right) \\
&= \frac{-1 + i}{\sqrt{2}}. 
\end{align}
From this: $z^{19} = 2^{9} \, (-1 + i)$.

Answer (score 1):

$z^2=2i \implies z^{20}=-2^{10} \implies z^{19}=\dfrac{-2^{10}}{1+i}=-2^{9}(1-i)=-2^{9}+2^{9}i$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(1+i\right)^{19}=\left(|1+i|e^{\arg(1+i)i}\right)^{19}=$$
$$\left(\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}\right)^{19}=\sqrt{2^{19}}e^{\frac{19\pi i}{4}}=\sqrt{524288}e^{\frac{19\pi i}{4}}=512\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{19\pi i}{4}}$$

So:

$$\Re\left(512\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{19\pi i}{4}}\right)=512\sqrt{2}\cos\left(\frac{19\pi}{4}\right)=512\sqrt{2}\cdot -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=-512$$
$$\Im\left(512\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{19\pi i}{4}}\right)=512\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{4}\right)=512\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=512$$